# Xampp Starting properly but in browser localhost is not working

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am using windows 7 and XAMPP Starting properly but in browser(ALL borwsers) localhost is not working incase of that some folders are displaying with the title searchbase. Please refer the screenshot [image]

Help me to debug this problem, I checked recently installed programs also browsers windows settings every thing looks fine.

Comment: thats weird, could you try other alternatives ? like WAMP for example.

Comment: @nodeffect the problem is The main project inside this.. And the things are working fine till yesterday :(

Comment: what happened between today and yesterday - obviously something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have the "Searchbase.exe" malware on your PC. Check your installed programs (Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall a program) for anything that resembles what you're seeing. It's probably hogging port 80. Might consider doing a virus scan.

Don't type anything sensitive into that engine. Looks weird...

Comment: Thank you @adamdesign.. Eventually you gave a idea.. The special part is its not listing in Control panel .. Found that location and deleted the files.. Working now :)